# где хранить текстовые данные текстовой игры?(swift)

Tags: ios

всем привет, подскажите, как и где хранить текстовые данные игры ios, игра с нелинейным сюжетом, все меняется в зависимости от выбора игрока, игра простая,текстовая.
Я так понимаю, что в коде хранить все - не правильно, подскажите какие есть другие варианты, спасибо.

Comment: Думаю тут очень много может быть вариантов ( sql ( локально и нет) , просто csv, json , xml и т.д.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В свете вашего предыдущего вопроса, ваша игра будет выглядеть примерно так например

Класс, который содержит информацию об одном шаге игры:

- идентификационный номер шага
- текст с описанием
- массив состоящий из

  - текст ответа
  - номер шага на который игрок переходит после выбора этого ответа

теперь это дело проще всего записать либо в json (который легко конвертируется в NSArray/NSDictionary, либо сохранить в файле plist который точно так же конвертируется.

более сложные решения:

- сохранить все это дело в coredata (я бы не советовал)
- хранить на сервере и запрашивать только нужный шаг (при этом вы можете менять содержание игры без изменения клиентского кода)

Answer (score 0):

- В файле ручками сохранять
- Realm
- CoreData